# Is there a relationship between Matrix norm and the Jacobian of same matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

The exercise asks us to show that a function $\mathbf{g}$ that is $C^{(1)}$, and $\displaystyle \exists_{c\gt0} \forall_{\mathbf{s,t}\in \mathbf{R}^n} |\mathbf{g}\left( \mathbf{s}\right)-\mathbf{g}\left( \mathbf{t}\right)|\geq c|\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{t}|$ has $\det (D\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{t}\right))\neq 0, \forall_{\mathbf{t}\in\mathbf{R}^n}$

I was trying to prove this by using some sort of relationship that could exist between $\det (D\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{t}\right))\neq 0$
 and $\|D\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{t}\right)\|$, taking advantage of the theorem that states for a function $\mathbf{g}$ that is $C^{(1)}$: $\forall\epsilon >0$, there exists a neighbourhood $\Omega$ of $\mathbf{t_0}$, such that$\forall\mathbf{s,t}\in \Omega$

$|\mathbf{g}\left( \mathbf{s}\right)-\mathbf{g}\left( \mathbf{t}\right)|\leq \left( \|D\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{t_0}\right)\|+\epsilon \right)|\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{t}|$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Part II

How do I prove that $\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{E}^n)=\mathbf{E}^n$. There is a hint that advise us to prove that $\psi(\mathbf{t})=|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t})|^2$ has a critical point, for any $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{E}^n$.

Comment: Taylor series, with remainder, for $g,$ around some fixed point $t.$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_matrix

Comment: and no, if $f(x,y) = 1234567 x,$ then the matrix norm of the Jacobian $J$ is large but $J$ still has determinant $0.$ Such a function fails the requirement of your problem, of course.

Comment: forget the matrix norm. irrelevant.

Comment: @WillJagy, thanks for your comments/help, but I don't get the point of the first one.How having $|D\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{t})\cdot \frac{\mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|}|+|\frac{o(\mathbf{h})}{\mathbf{h}}|\geq c\gt 0$ helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I take a fixed $p_0.$ Next, I find $J,$ which is the Jacobian of $g$ at $p_0.$

Now, assume that there is some vector $\vec{v}$ with $J\vec{v} = 0.$ We might as well **demand** $|\vec{v}| = 1.$

Now, we take a real parameter $r > 0.$

What does Taylor's Theorem with remainder say about 
$$ \color{magenta}{ g(p_0 + r \vec{v} ) - g(p_0)}   $$
as we let $r$ become very small, and what does that have to do with the hypothesis about $...\geq c |t-s| ?$

Comment: So, we will deduce that |Jv⃗ |>=c>0, reaching a contradiction.

Thanks, I think I get it now. ;)

Comment: Could you please check the recently added Part II? I'm at a loss there. Thanks in advance.